# Different \marginparsep for odd and even pages?

Tags: spacing, double-sided, marginpar

What is the most robust way of increase the effective `\marginparsep` on even pages only?

I have been playing with outdented lists, section heads etc. which leads to an issue with margin notes: I need to increase the effective `\marginparsep` on even pages to allow for the outdents.  Since this is a length, I cannot simply include a macro such as KOMA's `\ifthispageodd`.

If possible, I would like a solution that works with the standard `\marginpar` as well as with `marginnote` or similar packages.

**Update:**

Werner's answer below almost solves the problem, but there is a bug closely related to that fixed by `mparhack`.  This MWE demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\usepackage{mparhack}

\begin{document}
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {\global\marginparsep=22pt}% Next page is even
    {\global\marginparsep=11pt}% Next page is odd
}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize}
  \def\do#1{\item This is a line #1 and should have a note with the same
    number:\marginpar{Note #1 and a bit.}}
  \docsvlist{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3-5]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[6-8]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note 17 at the top of the second page does not receive the proper adjustment.  If the `mparhack` package is not used, then this note also appears on the wrong side of the page, so the full solution probably involves somehow applying a similar patch.   Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: The problem seems to be that when margin par is on the bottom of the page, it is moved to the next page. But all this is done before `\shipout` for the next page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key to solving this problem is the `mparhack` package, without which the circled margin par in the question update appears on the wrong side of the page. The `mparhack` package redefines the `\@addmarginpar` command to have:

```
\renewcommand\@addmarginpar{%
    ...
    \c@page=\mph@pg@new     % At this point, \c@page is correct
    ...
    \mph@orig@addmarginpar  % This typesets the note using \marginparsep
    ...
}
```

It is straightforward to use `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` package to insert my `\marginparsep` changes immediately before `\mph@orig@addmarginpar` which does the actual setting of the margin par.  This eschews the need for using `everyshi`.

A similar patch can be applied to `\@mn@@@marginnote` to solve the problem for `marginnote`, replacing `\kern\marginparsep` with a conditional statement.  This is a little more tricky because there are several places this needs to be changed, so we use the trick of recursively applying the patch until the `\patchcmd` fails (after there is nothing left to patch).

In principle, one might be able to replace `\marginparsep` everywhere with the appropriate conditional, but it seems non-trivial to properly determine the page parity, and independent tests have to be made in each case: `\ifodd\c@page` for `\marginpar` and `\ifodd\@mn@currpage` for `\marginnote`.

This is a somewhat messy hack, but I have not found a simpler working solution:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mparhack}

\newlength\marginparsepodd
\newlength\marginparsepeven
\marginparsepodd=11pt
\marginparsepeven=22pt

\makeatletter
% First we patch \@addmarginpar
% The \patchcmd command does a search and replace. 
\patchcmd{\@addmarginpar}                 % In this command
         {\mph@orig@addmarginpar}         % ... replace this...
         {\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\relax  % ... with this
              \marginparsep=\marginparsepodd  % Page is odd
            \else
              \marginparsep=\marginparsepeven  % Page is even
            \fi
          \else
            \marginparsep=\marginparsepodd
          \fi
          \mph@orig@addmarginpar}
         {}                                           % success
         {\message{Error! Couldn't hook into command  % failure
             `\string\@addmarginpar'}} 

% Now we patch \@mn@@@marginnote
{%% Group to keep patching commands local
  %
  % Here we use a little trick to repeatedly patch the \@mn@@@marginnote
  % command, replacing all instances of \kern\marginparsep with a
  % conditional. We call \patch recursively each time on success, and stop
  % when the patch fails (because all instances have been replaced).  If the
  % patch fails the first time, we show an error message.
  \def\patcherr{%
    \message{Error! Couldn't hook into command `\string\@mn@@@marginnote'}}
  \def\patchok{%
    \let\patcherr\relax % Only display error if first patch fails
    \patch              % Now patch again.
  }
  \def\patch{
    \patchcmd{\@mn@@@marginnote}                   % In this command
             {\kern\marginparsep}                  % ... replace this...
             {\ifx\@mn@currpage\relax\else         % ... with this
                \if@twoside\ifodd\@mn@currpage\relax 
                    \kern\marginparsepodd
                  \else
                    \kern\marginparsepeven
                  \fi
                \else
                  \kern\marginparsepodd
                \fi
              \fi}
             {\message{Patched!}\patchok}          % success (recurse)
             {\patcherr}                           % fail 
  }
  \message{Patching `\string\@mn@@@marginnote`!}
  \patch
  \global\let\@mn@@@marginnote\@mn@@@marginnote    % Make patch global
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize}
  \def\do#1{\item This is a line #1 and should have a note with the same
    number:\marginpar{Note #1 and a bit.}}
  \docsvlist{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3-4]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of working solution.]

Comment: I think this is really ugly, but could not find a cleaner solution.  I will wait a bit to accept my answer in case anyone has a simpler complete solution.

Answer (score 6):

I would think that accessing the page number at shipout would be robust enough. For this, use the [`everyshi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi). Here is a small trial run:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen

\begin{document}
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {\global\marginparsep=22pt}% Next page is even
    {\global\marginparsep=11pt}% Next page is odd
}

\lipsum[1]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[2-5]
\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}
\lipsum[6-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: Different marginparsep values for odd/even pages]

The key is to make the change `\global` within `\EveryShipout`, since it is grouped. You could apply similar modification to the `\marginparwidth`.

Comment: The bundle `KOMA` provides the command `ifthispageodd` which is also recommended by the documentation. (only suggestion)

Comment: @Marco: Tried it within `\EveryShipout` and it didn't work, so I reverted to the traditional `\isodd` from `xifthen`.

Comment: @Werner: `\ifthispageodd` works for me.  What problem are you having?  Note that your example is missing the following needed to correspond to your output: `\marginpar[This is a paragraph in the left margin]{This is a paragraph in the right margin}\lipsum[9-10]`.

This answer almost solves my problem, but I am having an issue with some lines at the very top of some even pages not getting the correction.  I am having a hard time reproducing this with a minimal example though right now...

Comment: @Werner: I have updated my question to demonstrate the issue I am having with lines at the top of even pages.  Do you have any idea how to apply a patch similar to that in `mparhack` to your solution?