# Inserting non-indented text in enumerate/outline

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I'm trying to insert non-indented chunks of text/image/graphs into an outline. I would like to avoid nested `enumerate` environments. Anyone have a simple solution using something similar to what I have below? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
    \1 Some text
        \2 Other Text 
            \3 Other other text
WANTED: to be able to insert text and graph here that is NOT indented
            \3 More other other text
        \2 More other text
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\hspace*{\dimexpr\linewidth-\textwidth\relax}` to move the following text all the way to the left side margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\noindent\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\color{red}\rule[-2in]{0.4pt}{2in}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.

        \hspace*{\dimexpr\linewidth-\textwidth\relax}\fbox{\color{blue}Nonindented material}

        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \end{itemize}
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \end{itemize}
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical red line shows you where the left margin is.

If you've got more text to insert, you can put it in a minipage whose width is set to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\color{red}\rule[-2in]{0.4pt}{2in}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.

        \hspace*{\dimexpr\linewidth-\textwidth\relax}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}

        \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
        \end{itemize}
    \item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
    \end{itemize}
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\item Random stuff. blah blah blah. More random stuff.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to allow for page-breaking across the "WANTED" text, then using a `minipage` would not help (since it keeps the contained text together in a box. For this you could use [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or a primitive `\parshape` to reflow the text block boundaries temporarily:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,lipsum}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Other Text
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Other other text \par
      {\parshape 1 -\itemindent \textwidth
      \lipsum[2-5]}
      \item More other other text
      \item More other text
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Some more text
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Some other text
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

I've grouped the `\parshape` settings to localize its effect for the scope of the "WANTED" text. Although not included, the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was added to produce the visible text block boundaries.

See [Wrap around a logo at bottom right of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42219/5764) for a short discussion on the use of `\parshape`.

Comment: How would you do the above using mdframed?