# Advanced Wrapfig

Tags: wrapfigure

Consider the following code and output.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{image.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How can I have the text follow the gradient of the triangle in the image?

Comment: On both sides? The `\parshape` primitive can handle this.

Comment: See [How to wrap text around a figure? (revised)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40806/5764); [Wrap around a logo at bottom right of page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42203/5764); [How do you create pull quotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45709/5764)

Comment: Just the left side, something like the circular pullquote, but linear gradient.

Comment: You can follow the `\parshape` procedures laid out in any of the above, linked questions. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\parshape` can be used in the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{triangle.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\null\hfill\smash{% Place image with adjustment for height/depth
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{triangle.png}}}%
\par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}% Correct for following paragraph

% \parshape <num lines> <indent> <width> ...
\parshape 12 0pt 0.5\textwidth
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+0.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+1.5\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+2.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+4.5\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+5.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+6.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+6.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

For a more programmatic way at dealing with this, you could use [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/). For such an approach, see

- [Very specific paragraph shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32997/5764)
- [Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764)

or other, related posts:

- [How to wrap text around a figure? (revised)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40806/5764)
- [Wrap around a logo at bottom right of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42203/5764)
- [How do you create pull quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45709/5764)

Comment: What package is able to wrap text around more complex shapes, such as  i.imgur.com/MsbsOVG.png or i.imgur.com/Apq8kdv.png or i.imgur.com/GxllBgA.png easier? I mean automatically wrapping around a shape without manually specifying coordinates for each line.

Comment: @skan: For that you'll have to create the shape and introduce the line widths to TeX to be used within a `\parshape` macro; something similar to [Very specific paragraph shape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32997/5764) and [Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764). The latter example showcases the use of XFig to draw the shape and export it using `fig2dev`. This should work via [cygwin on Windows](https://x.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I had already seen that threads, but I expected to find an easier or more automatic solution.

Comment: @skan: Yes, automation is what everyone's after. TeX isn't the same as Word that provides a WYSIWIG GUI-style interface. You'll have to program the content, and that's why you need to do it that way. AFAIK, there exists no (La)TeX package that can do this automatically. Perhaps in other languages...

Comment: I was thinking more in software like Indesign

Comment: @skan InDesign does have textual flow capabilities for sure... but you can [find that online fairly easily](https://youtu.be/zoPuwLpk1TI).

Comment: @Werner I don't mean to do it with Indesign but to get the same result in Latex.