# Wrap text around non rectangular image

Tags: graphics, floats, wrap

Is it possible to wrap text around a circle or around a polygon? Or do I have to insert linebreaks manually to the right places?

Comment: Related (duplicates?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118745/advanced-wrapfig http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape/