# A question related to "Advanced Wrapfig"

Tags: wrapfig

this is my code snipped I am experimenting with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}


% \parshape <num lines> <indent> <width> ...
\parshape 12 0pt \textwidth
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+4.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+1.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+1\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+2.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+2.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.5\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+4.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+5.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+6.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The original code is from @Werner ([Advanced Wrapfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118745/advanced-wrapfig)) (all credits to him).
I would like to "mirror" the shape of the text, i.e. the shape should be on the left-hand side, but I don't understand how to change the above code. Can anyone from the community help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax: `\parshape <n> <indent line 1> <text width line 1> … <indent line n> <text width line n>`

So to have a *shape* on the left, you have to replace `0pt` by the expected text indent and the second value should than be `\dimexpr \textwidth - <indent of this line>\relax`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}% Not needed for using `\parshape`

\begin{document}

% \parshape <num lines> <indent> <width> ...
\parshape 11
0pt \textwidth
1em \dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax
2em \dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
3em \dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax
4em \dimexpr\textwidth-4em\relax
5em \dimexpr\textwidth-5em\relax
4em \dimexpr\textwidth-4em\relax
3em \dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax
2em \dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
1em \dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax
0pt \textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

From LaTeX 2022-06-01 you can use `\dimeval{…}` instead of `\dimexpr …\relax`, and therefore a somehow more LaTeX like syntax:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% \parshape <num lines> <indent> <width> ...
\parshape 11
0pt \textwidth
1em \dimeval{\textwidth-1em}
2em \dimeval{\textwidth-2em}
3em \dimeval{\textwidth-3em}
4em \dimeval{\textwidth-4em}
5em \dimeval{\textwidth-5em}
4em \dimeval{\textwidth-4em}
3em \dimeval{\textwidth-3em}
2em \dimeval{\textwidth-2em}
1em \dimeval{\textwidth-1em}
0pt \textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

See [ltnews35](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews35.pdf) and [LaTeX for authors — current version](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf) section 5 for more information about `\dimeval`.

Note: If the LaTeX run reports `\dimeval` as unknown command sequence with the example above, your LaTeX installation is too old. Either update or use the `\dimexpr…\relax` version instead.

BTW: The last pair is not only used for line n but all lines >= n in the paragraph, if the paragraph has more than n lines.

For more information about `\dimexpr…\relax` see [The ε-TeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf), section 3.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Comment: Nowadays you can use `\dimeval{\textwidth-2em}`, which is simpler and more in line with the standard LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @egreg Yes, indeed. The question used `\dimexpr`. So IMHO keeping it for the answer, but using an easier to understand calculation could help. And it avoids comments: "This does not work, because `\dimeval` is undefined." ;-) Maybe I'll extend the answer later.