# How to block-out part of beamer-slides for "weather-man"

Tags: beamer

I want "weatherman"-functionality in my video-presentations, i.e., I'm in front of slide in say lower right corner (size e.g. 5cm x 5cm). Hence, I don't want text to run into that area where my body/head is going to be. Of course, I could cut lines manually, but it would be super-cool to have a template where the lower right corner of every slide, say size 5cm x 5cm (a quite big chunch of a Beamer-slide), is not "writeable" for text or lists and text is broken automatically. Is this doable?

EDIT:
Just changing margins is not what I look for. But in order to speak to «margins», what I want to acheive is small left and right margins for top part of slide (wide textwidth), but a very large right margin in the lower part of the slide (same left margin). The wide right margin in lower part would give room for the «weatherman», while the narrow right margin in top part would allow text flow «over» the «weatherman».

Comment: @erik Thanks, but no. I have edited the question. Simply changing the right margin would give space for the «weatherman», but I will not be able to use the space «above» the «weatherman» (have text floating around him, as with a graph in a paragraph)

Comment: Your question is more like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36848/non-rectangular-page-geometry, but I am not sure whether the answer there can be modified to work with your case.

Comment: Maybe you can try doing it with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin , but with beamer this would require a lot of manual adjustment. I suppose if you make all slides top aligned, and ensure that there is only one paragraph per slide, then you can do this universally. But that's not I think a very good solution.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks. I have tried cutwin, but as you suggest it works only for one paragraph. I also looked at the other question you suggested. Both cutwin and the other answer struggles with lists, which I use extensively in my slides.