# flip book in master thesis

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2

I am right now writing my master thesis in computer science about a visualization topic. Since the core stuff of my thesis is a complex 3D visualization that only quite sends its message through user interaction (click/drag/turn to view from different angles), my only option to get this message across on paper would be a bunch of screenshots.

30 screenshots side by side or spread across a couple of pages *should* be ok, but I thought it'd be rather nice to have some kind of flipbook where the screenshots are in a specific spot spread on consecutive pages.

Is this a good idea at all?

For now this is what I am using:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

since there are less screenshots than pages of my thesis I would start these on some specific page in the middle of the thesis (is that even a good idea, I'm starting to doubt this whole thing...) like this:

```
\cfoot[{
\IfFileExists{pics/s\thepage.png}{
\raisebox{-40mm}{\includegraphics[trim = 40mm 40mm 40mm 40mm,clip,height=40mm]{s\thepage.png}}}{\raisebox{-40mm}
{}}
}]{
\IfFileExists{pics/s\thepage.png}{    
\raisebox{-40mm}{\includegraphics[trim = 40mm 40mm 40mm 40mm,clip,height=40mm]{s\thepage.png}}}{\raisebox{-40mm}
{}}
```

So as you see I was putting the screenshots in the footer, which is also not ideal ( ideal would probably be an area on the lower right of the page where the screenshots would go and the text would wrap around, but I don't know how to do that).

So with this in place I can not really control the footer. the `\pagemark` jumps lower or highter when the pages start with the screenshots in the footer compared to those without screenshots, and also the sceenshots will end up very close to the text - I'd like to see a larger space there but I can't control the footer height.

What to do? I'm thankful for every input, also for people telling me: "don't do this!" ( or the contrary)

EDIT:
just so you know what I'm talking about:

[image: grain interface]

These are microstructures. The thick brownish/pink lines represent grains in copper. the greyish thing in the middle is the separating interface between the two grains. The thinner lines form a grid representing the crystal orientations. This output is quite customizable, I could change colors, switch of either grid, change the grid density and obviously change the view.

I was just now thinking of including for each grid one set of 3 thick Arrows that the eye could make out easier on paper. I'll probably do this. Also, I'll probably not go this way of doing the flipbook somewhere in the footer or margin, but actually put just a few of these shots consecutively as figures in the appendix.

Comment: Just my personal comment: I *love* the idea! I don't know how conservative your reviewers will be (aaah... academia...), but if they are just a tiny bit open-minded, they should enjoy it. I don't know if placing the figure in the center (?) with `\cfoot` would be ideal... Also, then you could place the page number in the header. And maybe this will be of help: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/fancyhdr-with-image-and-flowing-text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/fancyhdr-with-image-and-flowing-text)

Comment: Depending on the size of the image, I think that an image in the outer margin will be better (this means that you'll need a double sided layout). That way, the "reader" can easily flip through the pages to see the animation.

Comment: thx for the comments so far. If I place the page numbers in the header, won't the pages without a screenshot look awkward as there's nothing at the bottom? I'm still trying to figure out how large the images need to be, but it feels like the outer margin would be quite too small. Also I'd rather not differ too much from a standard layout (because, you know ... academia...). Also: why centered? If text doesn't flow around it, putting this in the footer not centered would leave a whole lot of space at the other side, which also seems not right

Comment: Interesting! Is this some type of "metallography" so to speak visualization?

Comment: Intriguing problem! A different way of getting the 3D image into your printed thesis might be to get a [lenticular print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_printing) of a scene, which you can apparently get for less than 10 USD: http://www.snapily.com/. I haven't tried this yet, but I'd love to hear how well this works for non-photographic stuff!

Comment: yes basically this is metallography, or rather materials science. @Jake that's some cool stuff. I actually do think this would look really cool as a 3D print of a Makerbot. But first of all I don't have one, or access to one, and second I doubt it would be accepted with my masters thesis

Comment: @MarkusHütter: Yeah, I can imagine that would work really well. Too bad that in scientific theses, "progressive" formats like that are probably not well received. Things would probably look different in more "visual" disciplines like visual design or architecture. One day, maybe...

Comment: @MarkusHütter Disclaimer Mechanical Engineer here done a bit of Materials Science. Now what happens next, if you are flipping the book what would image 1,2,3,4,5,6 represent? What do they tell us?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides these images would represent the same scene from a slightly different angle. It's supposed to show how the user would interact with it to get an idea of how these grain orientations on the interface actually relate to each other. this interaction only really conveys the 3dimensionality. in this picture you actually see a twin. Imagine a cube. spin that cube 60 degrees around a diagonal and you have this twin configuration where each cube represents a grain. cubes were the first approach to this, now it has evolved to gibberish... but as stated I'll improve on it! more arrows!

Comment: I *really* like this idea, but I must confess it's not my cup of tea when producing academic documents. Please don't get me wrong on this. IMHO the best option is to provide textual representation of your image. I once had a colleague who was visually impaired and she used some sort of assistive technology to enable access to printed texts. Sadly, those technologies cannot render images without a proper textual representation. I know it's difficult to describe 3D objects, but I think it's more accessible. Maybe you could provide this feature as an appendix and not alongside the thesis. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda thx for your input. I pretty much decided, that this will go in the appendix. Also it won't be too long - just as long, as there are tables and other stuff alongside the pictures. And also I'm describing this in detail...

Comment: @MarkusHütter: It's a great idea, I hope the final result looks cool. `:)`

Comment: Besides the question Count Zero pointed out this follow up question is also very relevant: [Non rectangular page geometry](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36848/non-rectangular-page-geometry).

Answer (score 4):

When I had acne on my face and was still in High School, I took a subject left over in the syllabus from the century before the last called spherical trigonometry. Now the interesting part of this course was its textbook. In order to read it, you had to wear a pair of paper glasses with a transparent red plastic color sheet and supposedly, when you looked at some figures they would spring into life and be transformed to 3D. They never did; even when we moved our heads into all sort of strange positions. The worst you couldn't read the figures with the naked eye either, as they were specially printed to be used with the glasses.

Your suggested embellishments to your Thesis margins or running heads reminded me of this. I don't think it is a good idea, especially in a Master Thesis. You can communicate the idea of motion of your visualizations perhaps on a page of 6-8 figures that have been drawn time-lapsed.

Think the equivalent of a microbiologist illustrating for example the growth of an amoeba over two days in a flip-book versus some time sequenced photos or diagrams. Now if anyone could come up with a flip-book that explains quantum mechanics that's another story.

Comment: This is pure genius! I'll just put some stereoscopic images of my visualization side by side and ask my reviewers to cross their eyes!! While I appreciate your tale of acne, you never seemed to miss the green plastic sheet in you paper glasses. So of what worth is this to me? This is not really comparable to amoeba growth, as you can easily distinguish details over a sequence of photos. If I show you one of my screenshots you'll be left asking what in the world you're supposed to make of a bunch of lines. Thinking about this I get the idea I have to improve my visualization-technique for paper

Comment: @MarkusHütter Here is an idea, post some screenshots and some explanatory details and see if the community can come up with some ideas.

Comment: I was about to do this, please see my update.

Comment: You should definitely look at Dror Bar Natan's work on perceived depth images. He has written free software to generate them, and they seem to be exactly what you need: http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/papers/PDI/

Answer (score 1):

You already have a solution for making a flipbook, but let me take this opportunity to point out that there now exists a LaTeX package for making flipbooks: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flipbook .